# Call action from parent component in Ember 2.x

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to call an action from a parent component in my route view.

mychild.hbs

```
{{#parent as |wrapper|}}
    <button {{action "animate"}}>Login</button>
{{/parent}}
```

parent.hbs

```
<div>{{yield}}</div>
```

mychild route (no actions)

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(
});
```

mychild controller

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
});
```

parent component

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

    actions: {
        animate() {
            console.log('ok');
        }
    },
});
```

How to call `animate()` from my component ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Isn't it a typo? Opening bracket is `#parent` and its enclosing one is `/animate-fadein`

Comment: @Pavol ooops ! missing syntax ;)

Comment: Could you write an [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/) to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: [Ember Twiddle example](https://ember-twiddle.com/fc29de8f90261a1e3407403353e6cae1?openFiles=routes.my-route.js%2C&route=%2Fmy-route)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the following code to this. Seems to be working.

```
<div>
    {{yield this}}
</div>

{{#my-component as |mc|}}
    <button {{action "doIt" target=mc}}>callDoIt</button> 
{{/my-component}}
```